# Processor factory output is full and factories have nowhere to ship freight. How do I fix that?

Tags: simcity-2013

My processor factory output is full and factories have nowhere to ship freight. How do I fix that?

I have 1 small trade depot which has 1 coal storage lot, 1 ore storage lot and 1 freight storage lot. I cannot add any more storage lots to my trade depot.

I have 1 big trade pot which only has 1 freight storage lot, and I cannot add more storage because it says "NOT APPROVED".

Also, my whole city has High TECH level, university running at full and 1 Electronics HQ, which earlier used to say NEED ALLOY Import from global, but somehow I fixed it with Recycling center.

Electronics HQ now has produced too much and its OUTPUT STORAGE is full. Same problem now arising to my factories "Closing because of no places to ship freight."

How can I fix my FREIGHT SHIPPING problem? I have no place for Municipal airport. How do I allow my factories to ship freight and my processor factory to sell processors?

I have 10,000,000$+ money and Income is 13500$ per/hr. Population is 100,000.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the freight, you need to build more freight storage lots.

For the processors, you need to build a processor storage lot, and set the trade depot/port to export.

Below is how to get more storage lots.

1. Build more trade depots. There is a limit of 4 storage lots per depot, but you can build as many trade depots as you need. Also in the edit tool, you can destroy any storage lots you no longer use.
2. There are two ways to unlock storage lots for the trade port.

   1. Plop the commerce division for the Electronics HQ.
   2. Plop the electronics division for the Trade HQ.

Comment: i have one big trade depot, which has only 1 Storage lot. It wont let me add any storage lot other than fright storage. Says "NOT APPROVED."

Comment: You can build another trade depot (the small one) and add more storage lots to your new trade depot.

Answer (score 0):

Factories want to ship freight to commercial buildings. Only if you don't have enough of those do they resort to the freight lots of your Trade Depots/Ports. Try adding more commercial zones.

The processor factory requires your Trade Depots/Ports to have open processor storage lots; according to your question you have none. Add a Processor Lot to your Depot (you say you have 3 lots currently, so you have room for a 4th unless you've built yourself into a corner) and start exporting them. As long as your traffic is decent your backlog should get out the door and you'll earn mad cash; do this at the start of a day just after midnight and you should be able to upgrade your Electronics HQ. Then give it a Commerce Division so you can add a Processor Lot to your Port. (Alternatively, add an Electronics Division to your Trade HQ, depending which one you can upgrade first.)

Comment: yes i have 3 storages. but it wont let me added 4rth. says "NOT APPROVED" I have all TOWN HALL unlocked buildings.

Comment: If you have 3 storage lots, it won't say "not approved". Maybe instead of *having* 3, you *added* 3 to the 1 freight lot that comes free with the main building for a total of 4?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug. A similar bug happens with recycling centers. When the storage lots get full, it shuts the facility down, and it won't seem to restart no matter what you do. I added 4 delivery trucks. I bulldozed a module to put a processor storage lot in the trade center, and I set it to export. I have a rail depot. And I've built a lot of 'expensive' buildings around this microprocessor thing, and I can't get it to export the product...